# c# get child application domain name excetion cause in main process

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have C# program that uses a main process that load mutiple instace of 
same dll, each on into new application domain.

I have handled excetions bubbled up from child domain to main domains
and I show them into handler of main domain.

But I want to know how can I access from exception that which child domain
causes the excetion. I want to know the name of application domain

Comment: How do you send exceptions from a child app domain to the main app domain? You need some kind of remoting there.

Comment: I did that by adding AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
             new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException); to my subdomain class that is called by manager main domain. and handled it, thanks